# How can I get the Google Speech API not to fail when my audio contains long silences?

Tags: google-speech-api

I am using the Google Speech API to transcribe audio, using the [long-running-recognize endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/speech/longrunningrecognize) through the [Python Cloud Speech API Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries).

My audio files are normally 15-90 minutes. In most cases the API call works fine, returning a transcription of my audio. However, if my audio contains long periods of silence (roughly more than a minute) the transcription fails. The error returned by the Python Client Library call is `google.gax.errors.GaxError: Server unavailable, please try again later.`

A simple working code sample (once you've downloaded the Python Cloud Speech API Client Library) is below:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types, enums

client = speech_v1.SpeechClient()
audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=filepath)
config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.ENCODING_UNSPECIFIED,
        language_code='en-US',
        enable_word_time_offsets=True,
        max_alternatives=30
)
# Start the async operation
op = client.long_running_recognize(
     audio=audio,
     config=config
)
# Wait for the operation to complete
response = op.result()
```

How do I get the Google Speech API to transcribe audio files with long periods of silence?

Comment: Just don't send the silence parts and skip them. Use some kind of threshhold which takes the noise level into account. If the volume is below the threshold just skip until you find something above the threshold.

Comment: @Crigges Do you mean break the audio file into chunks, where the silence just isn't put into a chunk? I'm hoping to avoid doing that. I upload my audio to Google Cloud Storage, then I send the Google Speech API the path of the file to transcribe. I'm not sending a stream of audio.

Comment: Before uploading the audio to the Clould edit the files in a way that they don't contain silence anymore

Comment: @Crigges I may end up needing to do what you suggest, but I'm hoping someone else has an easier option (ie a config option I can set). Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: np, this is why I didn't put it as answer just a suggestion as comment :)

Comment: @Connor: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ssoler I have not found a solution to this problem with Google speech-to-text, though IBM Watson's speech-to-text doesn't have the same problem so I've been using it (see https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/speech-to-text/). Maybe that will help?

Comment: Have anyone found any solution?